# C: create and declare an 2d array in a for loop with index values

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to create some 2d arrays according to user's input, and naming them with index value in a for loop. For example, if the user's input is 4, we create 4 2d arrays which names are "array1, array2, array3, array4". The reason why it's a 2d arrays because some string values are stored in them.

```
  int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
      char Cards + i [4][20]; //something like this?
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You can't have dynamic variable names in C. Use another array dimension.

Comment: Not possible as stated.  All identifiers (such as variable names) used in a C program must be established at compile time.

Comment: You can not declare variables like this. What you can do is add them to another array, effectively making it a 3D array and accessing them by using someArray[index]

Comment: Make one 3d array, like **char Cards[99][4]20]** so that **Cards[i]** now addresses a **[4][20]** 2d array.

Comment: Thank you guys, I would just store something in the first element to differentiate

Answer (score 1):

This is a common beginner misunderstanding. Variable names have absolutely no relation to user I/O nor do they exist in the linked executable. Names exists *solely* for the benefit of the programmer and nobody else. Therefore translating user input to variable names doesn't make any sense.

It rather sounds as if you should have a (possibly multi-dimensional) array with name meaningful to the programmer. You wouldn't name your dog "Dog1 because it's my first dog", now would you? Preferably name the array based on what you plan to store inside it. Then perhaps *resize* it depending on user input.